# C# switch case how to calculate

Tags: c#, switch-statement, case

Hey I´am trying to add two numbers together via switch case.

I have 3 inputs, number 1 and number 2. The 3rd input is the method which I´d like to calculate number 1 and 2 with(e.g `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, etc...)

Now the problem is how do I create something like "this" ? I´ve tried this way, but it does not work...
Is it possible to make switch case like this : `case %:`  ???

Thanks

```
string firstNumber; 
string secondNumber;
string method;

//get numbers
Console.WriteLine ("Get first number");
firstNumber = Console.ReadLine ();

Console.WriteLine ("get 2nd number"); 
secondNumber = Console.ReadLine ();

Console.WriteLine ("the method to calculate with"); 

Console.WriteLine (" 1:\"*\"");
Console.WriteLine (" 2:\"/\"");
Console.WriteLine (" 3:\"+\"");
Console.WriteLine (" 4:\"-\"");
method = Console.ReadLine ();

//convert
int methodNew = Convert.ToInt32 (method);
int firstNumberNew = Convert.ToInt32 (firstNumber);
int secondNumberNew = Convert.ToInt32 (secondNumber);

switch (methodNew) {
    case 1:
        firstNumberNew *=  secondNumberNew;
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine ("check the methods."); 
        break;
}

Console.WriteLine (methodNew);
```

Comment: You question is not clear. Can you describe `how do I make something it` ? Can you, actually, describe what is your goal?

Comment: Just wanted to edit it. But was not able because (I think) u were editing the post... sorry

Comment: what problem are you facing.?

Comment: thanks guys, seems like i got it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can read in a `char` and do a `switch-case`
for it:

```
int c = Console.Read(); // read from console
switch(c) {
    case '/':
        // work
        break;
    case '%':
        // work
        break;
    case '*':
        // work
        break;
    case '+':
        // work
        break;
}
```

Comment: But how does the two numbers get the right case ? 

Do I write under (e.g) 
case '/':
firstNumber/secondNumber 

I don´t really understand this step.

Answer (score 1):

First get the operator then use `switch` like this:

```
char method = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
double result = 0.0;
switch (method)
{
     case '+':
         result = firstNumberNew + secondNumberNew;
         break;
     case '-':
        result = firstNumberNew - secondNumberNew;
        break;
     case '/':
        result = firstNumberNew / secondNumberNew;
        break;
     case '%':
        result = firstNumberNew % secondNumberNew;
        break;
     default: 
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid value, try again");
        break;
}
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

It would be better if you change the type of `firstNumberNew` and `secondNumberNew` to `double`.Alşo you can  use a `while` loop to force user to enter a valid character.

Comment: Why do you multiply in the divide-case and divide in the modulo case?